# Game Object Factory: Fixing Memory Leaks

Tags: c++

Dear all, this is going to be tough: I have created a game object factory that generates objects of my wish. However, I get memory leaks which I can not fix.

Memory leaks are generated by **return new Object();** in the bottom part of the code sample.

```
static BaseObject * CreateObjectFunc()
{
    return new Object();
}
```

How and where to delete the pointers? I wrote **bool ReleaseClassType()**. Despite the factory works well, ReleaseClassType() does not fix memory leaks.

```
bool ReleaseClassTypes()
{
    unsigned int nRecordCount = vFactories.size();
    for (unsigned int nLoop = 0; nLoop < nRecordCount; nLoop++ )
    {
        // if the object exists in the container and is valid, then render it
        if( vFactories[nLoop] != NULL) 
            delete vFactories[nLoop]();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Before taking a look at the code below, let me help you in that my CGameObjectFactory creates **pointers to functions** creating particular object type. The pointers are stored within vFactories vector container.

I have chosen this way because I parse an object map file. I have object type IDs (integer values) which I need to translate them into real objects. Because I have over 100 different object data types, I wished to avoid continuously traversing very long Switch() statement.

Therefore, to create an object, I call **vFactoriesnEnumObjectTypeID** via CGameObjectFactory::create() to call stored function that generates desired object.

The position of the appropriate function in the vFactories is identical to the nObjectTypeID, so I can use indexing to access the function.

So the question remains, **how to proceed with garbage collection and avoid reported memory leaks?**

```
#ifndef GAMEOBJECTFACTORY_H_UNIPIXELS
#define GAMEOBJECTFACTORY_H_UNIPIXELS

//#include "MemoryManager.h"
#include <vector>


template <typename BaseObject>
class CGameObjectFactory
{
public:
    // cleanup and release registered object data types
    bool ReleaseClassTypes()
    {
        unsigned int nRecordCount = vFactories.size();
        for (unsigned int nLoop = 0; nLoop < nRecordCount; nLoop++ )
        {
            // if the object exists in the container and is valid, then render it
            if( vFactories[nLoop] != NULL) 
                delete vFactories[nLoop]();
        }
        return true;
    }

    // register new object data type
    template <typename Object>
    bool RegisterClassType(unsigned int nObjectIDParam )
    {
        if(vFactories.size() < nObjectIDParam) vFactories.resize(nObjectIDParam);

        vFactories[nObjectIDParam] = &CreateObjectFunc<Object>;
        return true;
    }


    // create new object by calling the pointer to the appropriate type function
    BaseObject* create(unsigned int nObjectIDParam) const
    {
        return vFactories[nObjectIDParam]();
    }


    // resize the vector array containing pointers to function calls
    bool resize(unsigned int nSizeParam)
    {
        vFactories.resize(nSizeParam);
        return true;
    }

private:
    //DECLARE_HEAP;

    template <typename Object>
    static BaseObject * CreateObjectFunc()
    {
        return new Object();
    }


    typedef BaseObject*(*factory)();
    std::vector<factory> vFactories;
};


//DEFINE_HEAP_T(CGameObjectFactory, "Game Object Factory");

#endif // GAMEOBJECTFACTORY_H_UNIPIXELS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't clean up from inside the Factory class. It's the job of whatever code called `create()` to deallocate that memory later. The "cleanup" you've done just allocates and then destroys a new object of each type.

Comment: @DeadMG: + 1 for good answer and spending effort looking into my long question. Hi, DeadMG, I store all objects returned with **BaseObject* create(unsigned int nObjectIDParam) const ** in separate vector elsewhere in my code. I clean those pointers. But I still get information about memory leaks on the mentioned line **return new Object(); **. Do you have an idea, please, if I should perform another cleaning? Can I delete pointers which I casted to different data types?

Comment: @Bunkai Satori: If you delete the pointers returned, then your tool is just wrong, and there's no two ways about it. The only way you could possibly improve it is by returning a smart pointer.

Comment: @DeadMG: so you say, I should not delete the pointers returned by **BaseObject* create(unsigned int nObjectIDParam) const** and instead I should implement smart pointers? I tried std::smart_ptr, but I was having the same memory leak on the line **return new Object();**

Comment: @Bunkai: You don't *have* any memory leak. It's your tool being wrong. You should use smart pointers wherever possible - but there's no memory leak in this segment of code if you delete the pointer returned by `create` correctly.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that when a tool says a certain line is responsible for a memory leak, it doesn't mean that line is wrong. It means you're doing something wrong with the code that handles whatever is created by that line.

Comment: @Kylotan, @DeadMG: thanks for your navigation. You are perfectly correct, that the pointer memory release is correct. I have HEAP CORRUPTION error DETECTED. It is related to the memory allocated by the line: **return new Object();** in the code above. I decided to solve problem one by one, and for the time being, I was overlooking Debug Error! window, as I did not think it would relate to reported memory leaks.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, heap corruption errors aren't memory leaks - they are symptoms of a time when you have written to an incorrect part of memory. You are probably writing past the end of an array or vector.